# How to include static library in makefile

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I have the following makefile

```
CXXFILES = pthreads.cpp 

CXXFLAGS = -O3 -o prog -rdynamic -D_GNU_SOURCE -L./libmine
LIBS = -lpthread -ldl

all:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFILES) $(LIBS) $(CXXFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f prog *.o
```

I am trying to include the `./libmine` library within `CXXFLAGS`, but it seems like it is not the right way to include a static library, because when I compile the program, I get many undefined references error. So what is actually the right way to include a static library in the makefile?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
CXXFLAGS = -O3 -o prog -rdynamic -D_GNU_SOURCE -L./libmine
LIBS = libmine.a -lpthread
```

Comment: OP added `-L./libmine` in `gcc` compilation and linking line but didn't add `libmine.a`.  `-L./libmine` tells `gcc` to look into `./libmine` directory to search for the objects files and libraries. Adding `libmine.a` tells `gcc` you want to link your executable with `libmine.a` library.

Comment: To clarify, LIBS = libmine.a does not work with -L./libmine. It seems absolute path is necessary.  Use LIBS = -lmine, it will look for either libmine.a or libmine.so (tested with gcc 5.4.0)

Answer (score 62):

use

```
LDFLAGS= -L<Directory where the library resides> -l<library name>
```

Like :

```
LDFLAGS = -L. -lmine
```

for ensuring static compilation you can also add

```
LDFLAGS = -static
```

Or you can just get rid of the whole library searching, and link with with it directly.

Say you have `main.c`, `fun.c` and a static library `libmine.a`.
Then you can just do in your final link line of the Makefile

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.o fun.o libmine.a
```

Answer (score 14):

Make sure that the `-L` option appears ahead of the `-l` option; the order of options in linker command lines *does* matter, *especially* with static libraries.  The `-L` option specifies a directory to be searched for libraries (static or shared).  The `-lname` option specifies a library which is with `libmine.a` (static) or `libmine.so` (shared on most variants of Unix, but Mac OS X uses `.dylib` and HP-UX used to use `.sl`).  Conventionally, a static library will be in a file `libmine.a`.  This is convention, not mandatory, but if the name is not in the `libmine.a` format, you cannot use the `-lmine` notation to find it; you must list it explicitly on the compiler (linker) command line.

The `-L./libmine` option says "there is a sub-directory called `libmine` which can be searched to find libraries".  I can see three possibilities:

1. You have such a sub-directory containing `libmine.a`, in which case you also need to add `-lmine` to the linker line (after the object files that reference the library).
2. You have a file `libmine` that is a static archive, in which case you simply list it as a file `./libmine` with no `-L` in front.
3. You have a file `libmine.a` in the current directory that you want to pick up.  You can either write `./libmine.a` or `-L . -lmine` and both should find the library.

Answer (score 11):

The `-L` merely gives the path where to find the `.a` or `.so` file. What you're looking for is to add `-lmine` to the `LIBS` variable.

Make that `-static -lmine` to force it to pick the static library (in case both static and dynamic library exist).

Addition: Suppose the path to the file has been conveyed to the linker (or compiler driver) via `-L` you can also specifically tell it to link `libfoo.a` by giving `-l:libfoo.a`. Note that in this case the name includes the conventional `lib`-prefix. You can also give a full path this way. Sometimes this is the better method to "guide" the linker to the right location.

Comment: I read about the `-static` flag, but I'm concerned that `-static` will make all the referenced libs static, when I just want one to be. Will `-static` mark only the proceeding reference as static?

Comment: @Cokemonkey11: any library after the `-static` should prefer the static version of the library, yes.

Comment: @0xC00000022L so if I do `-static -lfoo -bar`, both foo and bar will be static? I want only foo to be static - that's what I was trying to ask. Edit: I want only foo to be *explicitly* static, whereas I want bar to have standard linking behavior.

Comment: @Cokemonkey11: it will *prefer* the static version with `-lbar` behind `-static`. But if there is no static lib, it'll use what it finds, to my knowledge. Depends on the linker scripts you use with the GCC driver, though.