# How to know what external library files or locations need to be linked

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile

I'm new to c++ dev on linux, so I'm wondering:

**Generally how does one find out exactly what file(s)/locations need to be linked for an external library?**

I'm trying to link a library to my c++ project that I installed like so:

`sudo apt-get install libvlc-dev`

If I run `make` it will give me a bunch of `undefined reference` errors because the lib hasn't been linked. I read that I need to link it from somewhere in /usr/lib/.

In order to find the file(s) I need to link I did `apt-file list libvlc-dev` which returns:

```
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/deprecated.h 
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/libvlc.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/libvlc_dialog.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/libvlc_events.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/libvlc_media.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/libvlc_media_discoverer.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/libvlc_media_library.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/libvlc_media_list.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/libvlc_media_list_player.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/libvlc_media_player.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/libvlc_renderer_discoverer.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/libvlc_version.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/libvlc_vlm.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/include/vlc/vlc.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvlc.so
libvlc-dev: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libvlc.pc
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/bug/libvlc-dev/control
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/bug/libvlc-dev/presubj
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/doc/libvlc-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/doc/libvlc-dev/changelog.gz
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/doc/libvlc-dev/copyright
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/doc/libvlc-dev/examples/QtPlayer/LICENSE
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/doc/libvlc-dev/examples/QtPlayer/QtVLC.pro
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/doc/libvlc-dev/examples/QtPlayer/main.cpp
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/doc/libvlc-dev/examples/QtPlayer/player.cpp
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/doc/libvlc-dev/examples/QtPlayer/player.h
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/doc/libvlc-dev/examples/gtk_player.c
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/doc/libvlc-dev/examples/libvlc_DVD_ripper.c
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/doc/libvlc-dev/examples/vlc-thumb.c
libvlc-dev: /usr/share/doc/libvlc-dev/examples/wx_player.cpp
```

It looks like I'll need to link one of these I guess?

```
libvlc-dev: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvlc.so
libvlc-dev: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libvlc.pc
```

So based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11345385/1757149) makefile syntax:

`LDFLAGS= -L<Directory where the library resides> -l<library name>`

I would do:

`LDFLAGS= -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ -llibvlc`

Is this correct?

Comment: *You* don't bother. You tell your build system (cmake, meson, etc.) that you need the library, and make sure it can be found. Let the build system worry about that. I'd take it even further, let a package manager get the library for you, and then tell the build system that your package manager knows what's up.

Comment: I see, thanks... could you give me a hint at how I do such a thing?

Comment: If you haven't yet, I'd start by consulting the documentation of whatever library you're attempting to use.

Comment: Thanks, I did and did not find any seemingly helpful info. Anyway thank you for your original answer, it gave me a hint-- I removed -L flag and ended up with: `LDFLAGS=-lvlc` and it did compile and link successfully.

Comment: Also see https://man.archlinux.org/man/pkgconf.1.en

Comment: If packages come with a `.pc` file you can ask `pkg-config --libs` and `pkg-config --cflags` to output the correct linker arguments and compile flags, respectively. It even handles transitive dependencies for you!

Answer (score 2):

> Generally how does one find out exactly what file(s)/locations need to be linked for an external library?

One typically relies on the library's documentation for its name.  If that does not suffice, then you can look for a `lib*.so` file (typically these days) or a `lib*.a` file.  The library name is the part between the `lib` and the `.so` / `.a`.

Often, you don't need to know the specific location.  The linker has a search path for libraries that it will use to try to find the libraries you ask for.  On conventionally-organized systems, most libraries will be installed into directories on the search path, so all you have to tell the linker is `-l<name>` (see above).  For example, `-lvlc`.

If a library happens not to be installed in the linker's search path, then see above about recognizing the library file.  You would want to add the installation directory to the linker's search path via an `-L` option.  For example, `-L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu`.

> I would do:
>
> ```
> LDFLAGS= -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ -llibvlc
> ```

It dpends on how `LDFLAGS` is used, but it if it is used in your makefile or by your tools, but if it is used in the conventional way then **no, you would not**.

Many linkers are sensitive to the order of their command-line arguments.  `-L` arguments should appear before any libraries whose lookup they need to affect.  Libraries should be requested after the object files and other libraries for which they resolve any symbols.

`LDFLAGS` is not (usually) appropriate for flags specifying libraries to link.  It is conventionally expanded before the objects to be linked, so too early.  It is for link flags *other than* libraries.  If you're relying on GNU `make`'s built-in rules then you can put libraries in `LDLIBS`.  If you're using project specific build rules, or a different `make`, or whatnot then you'll have to figure out what the appropriate variable is, or whether to hard-code something, or perhaps the project comes with a pre-build configuration utility that you should use instead.

Comment: Also, it's `-lvlc` not `-llibvlc`.  The `lib` part is not part of the name.  No, I don't know why it was done that way but it's been like that since the 1970's or so.

Comment: I think I already said that, @MadScientist.

Comment: Yes; it just seemed to me you buried the lede since that was actually _the_ thing wrong in the question's example but it was mentioned only briefly at the end of the 3rd paragraph.  Sorry to be unclear myself.